# Paste 10000 records from excel sheet into a temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have 10000 records in an excel sheet and want to copy it to a temp table before inserting it to the actual table. I don't have permission to create an actual table on the database. Is there a way I can paste 10000 records into a temp table similar to the "Edit top 200 rows" function in a sql server database?

Comment: You can select from excel using openrowset. Here's a tutorial: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/read-import-excel-file-p01.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert Into #Temp
Select *
From MySpreadsheet
```

Any tablename preceeded by a pound (or hashtag, for you young whippersnappers) is a temp table.  Technically, though, you need to name each field instead of using the asterisk ("*").  So it's more like:

```
Insert Into #MyTempTable(Field1, Field2)
Select Field1, Field2
From MySpreadsheet
```

Comment: Or `select into ...` edit: come to think of it, not even sure if that works on temp tables...

Comment: Isn't "Select Into" only for appending data to a table that already exists?

Comment: No, the opposite, `select into` creates a new table. It would throw an error if the table already exists. BOL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx